# How can I cover a UI element from the parent UIViewController by a container with another UIViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm not sure if that's technically possible, but I'll give it a try.

I'm writing an app and on one `UIViewController` I've decided to put two containers, each of them has embedded (different) `UIViewController`. The first container is visible when user opens the app, the other one is hidden, and user can switch between them with Segmented Control:

[image]

This segmented control is always on top because user has the option to change the panels any time.

But there is one problem here. The first container contains `UIViewController` and there I also have the embedded container with a `UIViewController`, hidden by default. There is a button that changes `hidden` property to false and then the last `UIViewController` gets visible - I want to show it on fullscreen, but now the segmented control from the parent `UIViewController` is visible there. Is there a way to cover it/hide it?

Parts of the code are as follows:

The parent view with segmented control:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!   
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        firstView.hidden = true
        secondView.hidden = false
    case 1:
        firstView.hidden = false
        secondView.hidden = true
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Then the first panel with hidden container:

```
@IBOutlet weak var fullScreenComponent: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fullScreenComponent.hidden = true
}

func tapShowView() { //gets called on a button click

    fullScreenComponent.hidden = false

}
}
```

and then the fullScreenComponent is just a regular container with embedded `UIViewController` with some labels and buttons:

```
class FullScreenComponent: UIViewController{
...
```

How I can avoid showing the segmented control while presenting to the user the full screen component?

Answer (score 0):

You can post a notification when your tapShowView() function is called that is subscribed to by your parent view with segmented control.

For example in the parent view with segmented control add something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: "toggleSegmentedControl",name: "fullScreenTapped",object: nil)
}

func toggleSegmentedControl(){
    self.segmentedControl.hidden = !self.segmentedControl.hidden
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Then in fullScreenComponent change tapShowView to:

```
func tapShowView() { //gets called on a button click

    fullScreenComponent.hidden = false
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("fullScreenTapped", object:nil)
}
```

You'll need to post another notification when you come out of full screen mode as well.